# Analysis supremum proof

Tags: analysis

I have an assignment to do for my analysis class and I need help with a few of the questions.

Let $y$ be any real number and let $A = \{r \in \Bbb Q : r < y\}$. Prove that $y = \sup A$.

I would really appreciate any help  with this. 
Thank you

Comment: Is $A$ is seen as a subset of $\mathbb Q$ or of $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: The question doesn't explicitly specify, but i would assume  that it's a subset of R.

Comment: To prove $\text{sup}\,A = y$, what do you need to show? In other words, what would it mean for $y$ to be the sup of $A$?

Comment: We need to show that for y to be the supremum of set A, it needs to be the least upper bound of the set A.

Comment: Right. So first, is $y$ an upper bound of $A$ (temporarily not worrying about the _least_ aspect)? If so, justify.

Comment: Well since r<y, t that implies that r is bounded above by y. Therefore yes, y is an upper bound.

Comment: Fine. Next, suppose $A$ has an upper bound $x$ say,  which is less than $y$. To get a contradiction, what would suffice?

Comment: If we are assuming that there exists some other upper bound _N_ which is an element of set _A_, then for a contradiction to occur, _N_ would need to be less that Y ?

Comment: Let me ask it differently. If $p,q$ are real numbers with $p < q$, must there be a rational number strictly between $p$ and $q$? Why or why not?

Comment: Note: The upper bounds for $A$ don't have to be in the set $A$, They just need to be real numbers which are greater or equal to all elements of $A$.

Comment: i would think yes, that there should be some rational number between any two real numbers.

Comment: Assuming you can justify that, then if you assume there is some $x<y$, such that $x$ is also an upper bound of $A$, where's the contradiction?

Comment: If **x** is an upper bound which is less than _y_, this would imply that y is not the least upper bound for set A, which is a contradiction.

Comment: No, not right. You don't know that $y$ is the least upper bound of $A$. That's what you're trying to prove. Think about the discussion of rationals between two real numbers. What about a rational between $x$ and $y$?

Comment: More specifically, if $x < y$, and if $s$ is a rational number strictly between $x$ and $y$, must $s$ be an element of $A$?

Comment: May i ask, where are we supposed to incorporate _r_?

Comment: That's exactly the point. If $s$ is rational and $x < s < y$, then $s$ _is_ one of the $r$-values for the set $A$.

Comment: oh yes that makes sense. Ok so if x<s<y, then yes, _s_ must be an element of **A**, and since x and y are real numbers, then _s_ is some rational number of set A?

Comment: The key is that $s$ is rational and $s < y$. That forces $s \in A$. But then, if $x < s < y$, how could $x$ be an upper bound of $A$?

Comment: It can't be an upper bound then? Which then contradicts our assumption about _x_.

Comment: So $y$ must be the _least_ upper bound (done!).

Comment: Yes, i agree. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to MSE.